ちまった exact nuance?
ママの男が部下連れてやってきたわ。
こんな日にシフト入れちまったわ
The characters are two hostess talking in the back room.  Host 1 points out mama's man bought subordinates to which host 2 points out she ended up placing her shift in a day like this.
What nuance does ちまった provide here? Is it mean to sound like a complain? Like "oops, of all days I hate pick this one?"

Are you aware that 入れちまった is a contraction of 入れてしまった?

I think you have the right idea, and I don't think you really need to ask a question here.

(-て)しまう has two forms of contraction. See also this chart.

入れてしまう / 入れてしまった
入れちゃう / 入れちゃった
入れちまう / 入れちまった

ちゃう is generally safe in informal conversation. On the other hand, ちまう is rough and masculine, and it's typically used by users of 俺, ぜ, やがる, etc.
You may translate こんな日に as "of all days", but ちまった by itself is just a rough version of てしまった, and does not have such an additional nuance.

…ちまった (and its source …てしまった) definitely indicates worry/regret about what has happened.
